# Spark - SQL : value implicits is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

Tags: scala, hadoop, sbt, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Hi please find below code and corresponding errors :Even though i have used import statements but still giving errors

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("new_proj")
implicit val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val projects = sqlContext.read.json("/part-m-00000.json")
```

**[error] /mapr/trans.scala:25: value implicits is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
[error] import sqlContext.implicits._
[error]                   ^
[error] /mapr/ppm_trans.scala:28: value read is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
[error] val projects = sqlContext.read.json("/mapr//part-m-00000.json")**

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to compile code by changing the following  lines in build.sbt :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-core_2.10"              % "1.4.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-sql_2.10"               % "1.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-sql_2.10"               % "1.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10"             % "1.4.0"
  )
```